# How to work at different scales?

Tags: calculus, arithmetic

If I stroke $1$ inch horizontally on a sheet of paper and declare that length as $1$ mile. How far away from the ground should I be in order for my perspective to see $1$ mile on the ground the same as $1$ inch on a sheet of paper?

Should I consider my field of view and distance away from the paper as fixed/constant values as I move away from the ground?

Comment: Could you recall how many inches there are in a mile ?Otherwise, please, use metric system which is the common language now in science.

Comment: @JeanMarie 1 mile = 63360 inch. Meaning I would have to stroke 63360 inches horizontally on approximatelly 7,454 sheets paper with a horizontal width of 8.5 inches each. However, this entire experiment would be done on the ground. Which is not the issue at hand.